# Is there a way to group the MATLAB tabs?

Tags: matlab, interface

I am wondering if it is possible to group the related tabs in MATLAB editor. For example the tabs of methods belonged to the same class have the same color.

Assume I have method functions `a`, `b`, `c` which belong to class `A`. and method functions `aa`, `bb`, `cc`, `dd` that belong to class `B`. If you have many functions, navigating between them is sometimes confusing. But when you can group them by changing the tab color in editor or group them to a drop-down tab could help to recognize what class they are from faster. It is a big help for large number of classes and methods.
Thanks

Comment: can you show some examples? Because I faced the problem of splitting and union of tables several days ago and it works not for all situations!

Comment: OK, assume I have method functions 'a', 'b', 'c' which belong to class 'A'. and method functions 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd' that belong to class 'B'. If you have many functions, navigating between them is sometimes confusing. But when you can group them by changing the tab color in editor or group them to a drop-down tab could help to recognize what class they are from faster. It is a big help for large number of classes and methods. 
Thanks

Comment: aaah, now I got it. I really don't know is it possible. But you have to add this information to your question other people can see it